# Deleting Files and Removing from Git's Staging Index

Tags: git, version-control

When I delete a file like so

```
git rm file_name.ext
```

do I have to commit these changes? Why?

If I have to commit it, do I do it like this?

```
git commit . -m "Delete file_name.txt"
```

This is why I asked: I added the wrong file to Git's staging index

```
git add wrong_file.txt
```

so I removed it

```
git reset HEAD wrong_file.txt
```

but after doing so, I noticed this message

```
$ git reset HEAD wrong_file.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    test2.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       wrong_file.txt
$
```

and when I added the correct file to the staging index, I noticed that the test2.txt file that i deleted was renamed to right_file.txt

```
$ touch right_file.txt &&  git add right_file.txt
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       renamed:    test2.txt -> right_file.txt
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       wrong_file.txt
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest answer: "yes".  Until you `git commit` your changes are stored only in the index (staging area).  The `commit` operation takes all the staged changes and makes a new, single commit containing all of them, preserving them "forever" (unless you do things that "rewrite history", as it's called).

The "renamed" message from `git status` is based on comparing the file-to-be-removed to the one to-be-added.  If the contents match, git assumes (in the `status` output) that you must have renamed the file, rather than removing it and adding another.  For instance:

```
$ mkdir t; cd t; git init; git commit --allow-empty -m initial
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
[master (root-commit) bca9d63] initial
$ $ echo 'file contents' > somefile
$ git add somefile && git commit -m c1
[master c37af4b] c1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 somefile
```

Now I have a repo with two commits, the initial empty one and "c1" (`c37af4b`) containing `somefile`.

```
$ git rm somefile
rm 'somefile'
$ echo 'file contents' > newfile
$ git add newfile
```

I removed `somefile` and created a new file, but its contents are exactly the same as the file I removed, so `git status` detects this:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   renamed:    somefile -> newfile
#
```

Once I do the `git commit` I'll have a revision that no longer has `somefile` but does have `newfile`.  A `git diff` will also detect that the file looks exactly the same, and assume I renamed it:

```
$ git commit -m c2
[master a85cea2] c2
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rename somefile => newfile (100%)
$ git diff HEAD^
diff --git a/somefile b/newfile
similarity index 100%
rename from somefile
rename to newfile
```

The staging area (aka index) is where you arrange things until you like the arrangements.  Then you `commit` to freeze a copy of that arrangement, available forever more.  Until you `commit`, git assumes you're not quite satisfied yet.  `git status` compares the current stage arrangement against the `HEAD` commit and summarizes the difference*, and it doesn't really care how many times you added or removed or moved things around, it just compares "what the stage looks like now" against "what it looked like at the last freeze".

[*It also compares the stage to the working directory and summarizes *that* difference as "changes not staged for commit" and/or "untracked files".]